# How can I apply meet-in-the-middle algorithm for searching whole 2D matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I try to solve the [F. Xor-Paths](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1006/F) from Codeforces.

##### Problem statement

There is a rectangular grid of size n×m
. Each cell has a number written on it; the number on the cell (i,j
) is ai,j
. Your task is to calculate the number of paths from the upper-left cell (1,1
) to the bottom-right cell (n,m
) meeting the following constraints:

1. You can move to the right or to the bottom only. Formally, from the cell (i,j
   ) you may move to the cell (i,j+1
   ) or to the cell (i+1,j
   ). The target cell can't be outside of the grid.
2. The xor of all the numbers on the path from the cell (1,1
   ) to the cell (n,m
   ) must be equal to k
   (xor operation is the bitwise exclusive OR, it is represented as '^' in Java or C++ and "xor" in Pascal).

Find the number of such paths in the given grid.

---

I know that when `N = 20 and M = 20` then brute force won't work. But I don't have any better idea, I will explain why but let me explain my current approach.

That's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

bool bfs(int i, int j, long long k, long long curr_xor, const vector<vector<long long>>& a, int& count, vector<vector<unordered_set<long long>>>& bad_cells) {
    if (j == a[0].size() || i == a.size())
        return false;

    if (bad_cells[i][j].find(curr_xor) != bad_cells[i][j].end())
        return false;

    long long new_xor = curr_xor ^ a[i][j];

    if (i == a.size() - 1 && j == a[0].size() - 1) {
        if (new_xor == k) {
            ++count;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool right_valid = bfs(i, j + 1, k, new_xor, a, count, bad_cells);
    bool down_valid = bfs(i + 1, j, k, new_xor, a, count, bad_cells);

    if (!right_valid) bad_cells[i][j + 1].insert(new_xor);
    if (!down_valid) bad_cells[i + 1][j].insert(new_xor);

    return right_valid || down_valid;
}

long long solve(int n, int m, long long k, const vector<vector<long long>>& a) {
    int count = 0;
    vector<vector<unordered_set<long long>>> bad_cells(n + 1, vector<unordered_set<long long>>(m + 1));
    bfs(0, 0, k, 0, a, count, bad_cells);

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);

    int n, m;
    long long k;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;

    vector<vector<long long>> a(n, vector<long long>(m));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << solve(n, m, k, a);
}
```

So as you can see, my approach is pure brute force. I have recursive method `bfs` that increments the final `count` when we reach the final point `(n, m)`, and from every cell `(i, j)` it goes down and right. During moving over grid it calculates the XOR.

It also maintaints the `bad_cells` 2D matrix, that on `(i, j)` stores the values of XOR that won't drive us to good result. In other words, when we are at destination `(n, m)` point and our recursion starts to go back, then we check if the child met the problem conditions (final XOR == k). If no, we say that if you are at `(i, j)` with XOR equal to `new_xor` (parent XOR), if you go right or down (depends on what child returns), then you won't get valid result, I was here before and I know. Something like that.

Finally, I return true if any of the path (right or down) is correct, because if one of them is, then I can also look for other correct paths after the some correct move.

---

Of course, this is too slow. I get the TLE on 4-th testcase at Codeforces. The problem on Codeforces has tag `meet-in-the-middle`, so I probably need to use this technique. But how?

I imagine that I can solve it for e.g. (n/2)*m grid, and then for the another half and combine the results. But what will be the destination point for the first half (there is no `(n, m)` in the first half range). I think I could solve the first half in loop, by moving the destination point like `(n/2, i)` and then solve the second half also in loop by using `(n/2, i)` as starting point and `(n, m)` as the destination point, and then combine the results.

But it probably will be even slower. So how to solve if in a more efficient way? How to apply Meet-In-The-Middle technique to this problem?

Comment: Every valid path must go through a cell in the middle row (or middle column). Find all possible paths from (1,1) to each cell that row/column. Then find all possible paths from each cell in that row/column to (n,m). Depending on the values of n, m and given the constraints on movement, you may be able to eliminate some cells in the middle row/column from consideration. Calculate the XOR values for each possible half-path. Then check all possible full paths through each cell of the middle row/column.

Comment: Just FYI: The brute force solution has to search fact(N+M)/fact(N)/fact(M) paths, each of length N+M.  That's quite the ugly asymptotic behavior.  Dynamic programming should help, since it can collapse all path fragments that end in the same cell with the same XOR result... if a(i,j) is a relatively narrow datatype (say 8 bits) that could help a whole lot.  On the other hand if a(i,j) is a very wide datatype, you may find certain bits in the result that can only be set by a small number of intermediate cells, which therefore the path must include and breaks the problem into smaller ones.

Comment: Every qualifying path has n + m - 2 steps. Using a middle row to 'meet in the middle' will mean one side could have a lot more steps than are needed. I would find the xor values from both directions to the cells which are (n+m-2)/2 steps from the initial cell.

Comment: @rossum So as I stated in question, I would need to solve these two halfes in loop - for first half with different destinations (whole middle row), and for the second half with different starting points (whole middle row too). How and why can I eliminate some cells from middle? I don't see it.

Comment: @SimonGoater Why only n + m - 2 steps gives chance for qualifying path? Who said that I cannot do n*m steps (e.g. every cell is 0 and k = 0) and say that's a good path?

Comment: @Szyszka947 The question says you can only move right or down, you start at 1,1 and end at n,m. That has to be (n-1) + (m-1) steps.

Comment: @SimonGoater Ah I see. Every path has to have length of (n-1)+(m-1). How many points that needs (n+m-2)/2 steps to be reached from (1,1) are there? Lets say `x = (n+m-2)/2`, then there will be 3 points: `(1, 1+x)` and `(1+x, 1)` or also something like ((n-1)/2, (m-1)/2). Because we can more right and down, I don't see any other possibilities. So we have 3 destinations for every case and 3 starting points for the second half.  Having XOR of these paths, I just need to generate subsets from XOR's given by first half and second half and combine them. Seems not bad, but did I understand well?

Comment: You should process each 'middle' cell in turn so you can discard paths as you go. Just count the number of paths through (a_i, b_i) that XOR to k, then go to (a_{i+1}, b_{i+1}) etc. accumulating the counts. We know there are a+b-2 steps to (a,b) and W = (a+b-2 choose a-1) paths. There are 35,345,263,800 paths in total from (1,1) to (20,20) but only 48,620 to (10, 10).

Comment: @Szyszka947 You are right, you need to consider all cells in the middle row/column, you can't eliminate any. I wasn't thinking clearly about that part. Sorry.

Comment: Brute force will be some recursive backtracking...

Comment: @Szyszka947 I have been working on your question today. My detailed answer takes 300+ lines in markdown form in VS code, and I have yet to include the final code. It is possibly the most detailed, longest answer I have ever redacted for SO. I am just wondering if it is too long for you?

Comment: @Atmo I will read every answer as soon as possible, I need to find some time for it. But if it's very long code, then isn't it another brute force? I'm mostly interested in the part I asked in bounty. But don't worry, I will read your answer :)

Comment: There is a brute-force alternative (that I am unsure to keep) because it is a better starting point for code optimization but no, it is about MITM with a lot of explanations. It is basically the full reasonning + some code at the end. There is a lot of theory to understand to see where MITM is coming from here. Basically, I explain why a 20x20 matrix ends up with the calculation of >35 billion figures with the brute-force approach and how to cut it to 1048576 + everything that makes the algorithm valid + some detours to explore (and discard) before finding the right solution

Comment: @Atmo I can't wait to see it :D

Comment: Had to reformat the whole markdown to make it work in Stackoverflow (VS code has a different flavor) but that is finally here. Enjoy and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In advance, sorry for the length of the answer...

I have structured my answer as the complete reasonning that leads to the implementation of the meet-in-the-middle (MITM) algorithm for this question.
Instead of just implementing and seeing if it works, I detailed some of the underlying math, the overall algorithm, the subtle traps to avoid.

In this answer:

- First, I will address the elephant in the room as to exactly why the bruteforce approach did not work (and likely won't work even with optimized versions of it).
- I will propose an alternative implementation, which I think is slightly easier to understand than yours and is easier to take as a starting point for optimization.
- Next, I will list facts and properties the algorithm may (or not) use as exhaustively as possible.
- Following that, I will go into the overview of MITM.
- In continuity to the above point, I will detail where the magic happens in a separate point.
  The entire algorithm lies on that trick so it deserves its own separate section.
- Finally, I will include an implementation.

As you are only trying to solve a problem on codeforces, I strongly recommend you give it a try before reading the final section.

#### Why it failed / Why MITM is promising for this problem

The question specifies the matrix in input may be as big as 20x20 cells and the program should execute within 3secs and under 256MB of memory.

On a 20x20 matrix, it takes 38 moves to go from the top left cell to the bottom right cells: 19 of these moves are to go right and 19 to go down. The only choice we have is which moves, numbered from 1 to 38, will go e.g. right.
Therefore, the total number of paths in this situation is binomial(38, 19) = 35,345,263,800, too many to fit in the limitations set by the site.
Remember this figure, it will be important later.

The MITM algorithm should be able to cut path lengths in 2.
What we hope is to make combinatorics work in our favor, i.e. get a number of half paths to be in the range of binomial(19, 9) = 92,378 (in fact 2x figure since each complete path is made of 2 half paths).
Nothing is confirmed yet (the actual figure is in fact bigger and this difference will not materialize without heavy lifting anyway) but for now, let us simply consider this as a strong clue that something could happen.

#### Alternative brute-force approach

The issue (at least IMHO) with the code in the question is that I find it difficult to optimize. I prefer working with the below brute-force code instead:

- The algorithm is not recursive and does not use backtracking nor anything complicated. It only has a nested 2-deep loop.
- Moreover, I created a `Matrix` helper class to avoid seeing `std::vector<std::vector<...>>`.
  It encapsulates a single `vector`, and maps row/column coordinates to vector indices.
- Unlike you, I have translated the constraint given in the question that "0 ≤ k ≤ 10^18" into `uint64_t` (`unsigned long long` would have worked). I acknowledge `signed long long` works too though.
- For illustration, I have included a measure of the processing time in `std::cerr`.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//The matrix is not the core of the problem, so this simple class will do.
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns) : rowCount(rows), colCount(columns), v(rows* columns) {}
    uint64_t* operator[](unsigned int r) { return &(v[r * colCount]); }

private:
    unsigned int rowCount, colCount;
    std::vector<uint64_t> v;
};

//Read the matrix from std::cin
void read(Matrix& inputMatrix, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns)
{
    for (unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < columns; ++c) {
            uint64_t value = 0; std::cin >> value;
            inputMatrix[r][c] = value;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    using XorValueList = std::vector<uint64_t>;

    unsigned int rows, columns;
    uint64_t expected;
    std::cin >> rows >> columns >> expected;

    // Construct the a matrix of the right size
    Matrix inputMatrix(rows, columns);
    // Fill the matrix with data from std::in
    read(inputMatrix, rows, columns);

    // xorRow represents the current row being processed. Since we can never go up, we do not need to remember what is above it.
    // It stores the list of XOR results for all the paths leading to the corresponding cell
    std::vector<XorValueList> xorRow;

    auto start = steady_clock::now();

    // On the first row, only 1 path (horizontal) can reach each of the cells and there are no cells above.
    // The top left cell is a special case.
    xorRow.push_back({ inputMatrix[0][0] });
    // First row
    for (unsigned int c = 1; c < columns; ++c) {
        auto v = xorRow[c-1][0];
        xorRow.push_back({ v ^ inputMatrix[0][c] });
    }


    //Next rows
    for (unsigned int r = 1; r < rows; ++r) {
        // xorRow2 is the next row after xorRow.
        // It will be filled, then swapped with xorRow for the next loop / for after the loop
        std::vector<XorValueList> xorRow2;
        { // The first column is always a special case
            auto v = xorRow[0][0];
            xorRow2.push_back({ v ^ inputMatrix[r][0] });
        }
        //The other cells consist in taking the matrix value at that cell and combining it using xor with what we calculated on its left and above it.
        for (unsigned int c = 1; c < columns; ++c) {
            xorRow2.push_back({ });
            for (auto v : xorRow2[c - 1])
                xorRow2[c].push_back(v ^ inputMatrix[r][c]);
            for (auto v : xorRow[c])
                xorRow2[c].push_back(v ^ inputMatrix[r][c]);
        }
        std::swap(xorRow, xorRow2);
    }

    //The bottom right cell of the matrix contains all the desired path values
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (auto v : xorRow[columns - 1]) {
        if (v == expected)
            result += 1;
    }
    std::cout << result;

    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    auto ms_int = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cerr << "\nTime spent: " << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Useful properties of XOR (*notation:* ⨁) and the matrix

Time to list some properties; we do not know yet if they are going to be useful for our case:

The (bitwise) XOR operator has the following properties:

- Associativity: (A ⨁ B) ⨁ C = A ⨁ (B ⨁ C) = A ⨁ B ⨁ C
- Commutativity: A ⨁ B = B ⨁ A
- Neutral operand: A ⨁ 0 = A
- Negation: A ⨁ A = 0
  Spoiler alert: combining the above properties is going to give us a very important equivalence:
  A ⨁ B = E <=> A ⨁ E = B
  This can be easily verified using all 4 properties above.
- No carry with bitwise XOR: to store the result of A ⨁ B = C, C simply needs to have the same number of bits as A and B.

Other properties might be useful:

- The MITM approach works because of the associativity property; here, this is best expressed as:
  A ⨁ B ⨁ C ⨁ D = (A ⨁ B) ⨁ (C ⨁ D) = L ⨁ R (with L and R being the left and right operands of the MITM approach).
  As a general rule, identifying what makes an algorithm (not only MITM) possible is **the very first thing you MUST do**.
  If you don't have that, you can forget about solving everything else.
- A single path leads to cells on the first row and on the first column.
  Similarly, a single path leaves from the cells on the last row and on the last column.

#### MITM - Overview

The principle behind the MITM algorithm is to turn long chains of XOR operations into expressions involving only 2 operands: L ⨁ R where L and R are the results of xor operations.
 As often, the best way to split the left and right operands is indeed in the middle (L and R are calculated from roughly the same number of matrix values), hence the name of the algorithm.

There are 2 obvious ways you may split a matrix in halves (although that is not what I tried first...). I am marking with an `x` the matrix cells making the division, assuming they will be included in the left operand L, excluded from the right operand R:

1. Left and right:

   | R\C | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 0 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
   | 1 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
   | 2 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
   | 3 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
   | 4 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
   | 5 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
2. Up and bottom:

   | R\C | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 0 | L | L | L | L | L | L |
   | 1 | L | L | L | L | L | L |
   | 2 | `x` | `x` | `x` | `x` | `x` | `x` |
   | 3 | R | R | R | R | R | R |
   | 4 | R | R | R | R | R | R |
   | 5 | R | R | R | R | R | R |

Both are equivalent (at least in terms of complexity; they may not be equal when considering how `std::vector` caches its data), let us see the complexity for the left and right split and a 20x20 matrix. Let us count the paths leading/leaving to each of these `x` cells

| With | ... moves right | and … moves down, | path # leading to `x` | Then | … moves right | and … moves down, | path # leaving `x` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 9 | 0 | 1 |  | 9 | 19 | 6906900 |
|  | 9 | 1 | 10 |  | 9 | 18 | 4686825 |
|  | 9 | 2 | 55 |  | 9 | 17 | 3124550 |
|  | 9 | 3 | 220 |  | 9 | 16 | 2042975 |
|  | 9 | 4 | 715 |  | 9 | 15 | 1307504 |
|  | 9 | 5 | 2002 |  | 9 | 14 | 817190 |
|  | 9 | 6 | 5005 |  | 9 | 13 | 497420 |
|  | 9 | 7 | 11440 |  | 9 | 12 | 293930 |
|  | 9 | 8 | 24310 |  | 9 | 11 | 167960 |
|  | 9 | 9 | 48620 |  | 9 | 10 | 92378 |
|  | 9 | 10 | 92378 |  | 9 | 9 | 48620 |
|  | 9 | 11 | 167960 |  | 9 | 8 | 24310 |
|  | 9 | 12 | 293930 |  | 9 | 7 | 11440 |
|  | 9 | 13 | 497420 |  | 9 | 6 | 5005 |
|  | 9 | 14 | 817190 |  | 9 | 5 | 2002 |
|  | 9 | 15 | 1307504 |  | 9 | 4 | 715 |
|  | 9 | 16 | 2042975 |  | 9 | 3 | 220 |
|  | 9 | 17 | 3124550 |  | 9 | 2 | 55 |
|  | 9 | 18 | 4686825 |  | 9 | 1 | 10 |
|  | 9 | 19 | 6906900 |  | 9 | 0 | 1 |

If we do a sum-product of the 2 columns counting the paths (each half-path leading to an `x` cell can be combined with all the half-paths leaving it), we get back to 35,345,263,800. This is the figure we already calculated, and it shows how the numbers hold up.

The only issue with the split is that the total number of half paths (40,060,020), multiplied by the size of a 64-bit integer, exceeds 256MB. The excess memory consumption surely can be mitigated by doing some cleaning in the middle of the process but it is not ideal.

Let us see what happens with an alternative split, parallel to the 2nd diagonal.
For the record, this is what I tried first; but rather than just telling you to go with it, I find it more interesting for you if I explain the flaws of the 2 other alternatives:

| R\C | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | L | L | L | L | L | `x` |
| 1 | L | L | L | L | `x` | R |
| 2 | L | L | L | `x` | R | R |
| 3 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
| 4 | L | `x` | R | R | R | R |
| 5 | `x` | R | R | R | R | R |

For a 20x20 matrix

| With | ... moves right | and … moves down, | path # leading to `x` | Then | … moves right | and … moves down, | path # leaving `x` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 19 | 0 | 1 |  | 0 | 19 | 1 |
|  | 18 | 1 | 19 |  | 1 | 18 | 19 |
|  | 17 | 2 | 171 |  | 2 | 17 | 171 |
|  | 16 | 3 | 969 |  | 3 | 16 | 969 |
|  | 15 | 4 | 3876 |  | 4 | 15 | 3876 |
|  | 14 | 5 | 11628 |  | 5 | 14 | 11628 |
|  | 13 | 6 | 27132 |  | 6 | 13 | 27132 |
|  | 12 | 7 | 50388 |  | 7 | 12 | 50388 |
|  | 11 | 8 | 75582 |  | 8 | 11 | 75582 |
|  | 10 | 9 | 92378 |  | 9 | 10 | 92378 |
|  | 9 | 10 | 92378 |  | 10 | 9 | 92378 |
|  | 8 | 11 | 75582 |  | 11 | 8 | 75582 |
|  | 7 | 12 | 50388 |  | 12 | 7 | 50388 |
|  | 6 | 13 | 27132 |  | 13 | 6 | 27132 |
|  | 5 | 14 | 11628 |  | 14 | 5 | 11628 |
|  | 4 | 15 | 3876 |  | 15 | 4 | 3876 |
|  | 3 | 16 | 969 |  | 16 | 3 | 969 |
|  | 2 | 17 | 171 |  | 17 | 2 | 171 |
|  | 1 | 18 | 19 |  | 18 | 1 | 19 |
|  | 0 | 19 | 1 |  | 19 | 0 | 1 |

Again, the sum-product is equal to 35,345,263,800. What is interesting for us here is that the total count of the half paths is only 2^20 = 1,048,576.

To be complete, let us see what a diagonal split on a non-square matrix should look like:

| R\C | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | L | L | L | L | `x` | R |
| 1 | L | L | L | `x` | R | R |
| 2 | L | L | `x` | R | R | R |
| 3 | L | `x` | R | R | R | R |

#### The magic finally happens

So far, we have split paths in 2 halves, getting 2 lists of XOR'ed values at each `x` cell and it feels we need to compare them 2 by 2.
If we take the middle cell of the matrix, combining the values of each of the 92,378 paths leading to the cell with the 92,378 paths leaving it results in 8,533,694,884 comparisons. Repeat that for all the `x` cells and we get 35,345,263,800 XOR operations to do.
In other words, no time saved...

This is **the second thing you need to check when implementing MITM**: unless we find a trick to avoid having to recombine *all* the elements of the first half with *all* the elements of the second half, no time will be saved.

Now is the time to remember the equivalence I highlighted in the "Useful properties" section.
Instead of calculating all the possible XOR combinations, we can take all the XOR values from one of the operands (e.g. the left one) and combine them with the expected result, we get numbers comparable to the XOR values from the other operand.
Remember: to test if L ⨁ R = k, we can test if L ⨁ k = R.

Doing so leaves us with 2 lists in which we want to find the elements they have in common (i.e. the equal sign between L ⨁ k and R).
This, unlike the initial problem, does not need to compare all the elements from 1 list with all the elements from the other: after sorting both lists, we can compare them in the same fashion as we do a merge in a merge sort.
As we have split the matrix in order to minimize the number of half-paths, the 2 operations are short.

#### Implementation

It is finally time for some code.

> I would like to reiterate that you really should give it a try yourself before continuing to read. The best way for you to improve is by trying to do it yourself after all.

Before diving into the solution, a few final considerations:

- Just mentionning it for other readers, in case they have never encountered it: in C++ the bitwise XOR operator is `^`.
- As per the problem statement, the result k (and the values inside the matrix) will be between 0 and 10^18.
  This translates into a `unsigned long long`/`uint64_t` variable (for most compilers, `unsigned long` would do but the standard states `unsigned long` may only be 32 bits).
- The matrix size is dynamic, with 1 to 20 rows and 1 to 20 columns. Already presented in the alternative brute-force algorithm, the `Matrix` class takes care of it.
- Unlike real production code, I will assume the input provided is always as described in the problem's text. In theory, we should check data is only positive integers within the expected bounds, that at each row, we receive the expected number of integers and finally, that we receive the expected number of rows, etc.

Just so you know, I have not tried to do any optimization of the below code, whatsoever. The performance improvement is entirely due to the MITM algorithm. It is faster and seems to fit within 256MB but it may not pass the codeforces tests without a little bit of additional tuning:

- An easy way to speed things up is to call `std::vector<T>::reserve` before writing the XOR combinations, so that no reallocation would take place during `push_back`s.
- An easy way to further save memory is to calculate path 1 `x` cell at a time (the below code does all the half paths before it tries to combine them) and, of course, clean memory before switching to the next `x` cell.
- There are probably additional improvements e.g. if you manage to calculate the right operand without rotating the matrix 180°.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//The matrix is not the core of the problem, so this simple class will do.
class Matrix {
public:
   Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns) : rowCount(rows), colCount(columns), v(rows* columns) {}
   uint64_t* operator[](unsigned int r) { return &(v[r * colCount]); }
   //flip causes the matrix to do a 180° rotation
   void flip() { std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end()); }

private:
   unsigned int rowCount, colCount;
   std::vector<uint64_t> v;
};

//Read the matrix from std::cin
void read(Matrix& inputMatrix, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns)
{
   for (unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
       for (unsigned int c = 0; c < columns; ++c) {
           uint64_t value = 0; std::cin >> value;
           inputMatrix[r][c] = value;
       }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   using std::chrono::steady_clock;
   using std::chrono::duration_cast;
   using std::chrono::duration;
   using std::chrono::milliseconds;

   using XorValueList = std::vector<uint64_t>;

   unsigned int rows, columns;
   uint64_t expected;
   std::cin >> rows >> columns >> expected;

   // Construct the a matrix of the right size
   Matrix inputMatrix(rows, columns);
   // Fill the matrix with data from std::in
   read(inputMatrix, rows, columns);


   //The split position will determine where the left and right operands should meet.
   // If the matrix is not squared, it may not be inside it. 
   auto splitPosition = (rows + columns + 1) / 2;

   auto start = steady_clock::now();

   //This lambda is in charge of filling the 2 MITM operands
   //It is built for the left operand but as the matrix can be rotated 180°, works for the right operand too.
   auto fillXorOperand = [rows, columns, &splitPosition, &inputMatrix](std::vector<XorValueList>& xorOperand)
   {
       // xorRow represents the current row being processed. Since we can never go up, we do not need to remember what is above it.
       // It stores the list of XOR results for all the paths leading to the corresponding cell.
       std::vector<XorValueList> xorRow;

       // On the first row, only 1 path (horizontal) can reach each of the cells and there are no cells above.
       // The top left cell is a special case.
       xorRow.push_back({ inputMatrix[0][0] });
       // First row
       for (unsigned int c = 1; c < columns && c < splitPosition; ++c) {
           auto v = xorRow[c - 1][0];
           xorRow.push_back({ v ^ inputMatrix[0][c] });
       }
       if (columns >= splitPosition)
           xorOperand.push_back(xorRow[std::min(columns, splitPosition) - 1]);

       //Next rows
       for (unsigned int r = 1; r < rows && r < splitPosition; ++r) {
           // xorRow2 is the next row after xorRow.
           // It will be filled, then swapped with xorRow for the next loop / for after the loop
           std::vector<XorValueList> xorRow2;
           { // The first column is always a special case
               auto v = xorRow[0][0];
               xorRow2.push_back({ v ^ inputMatrix[r][0] });
           }
           //The other cells consist in taking the matrix value at that cell and combining it using xor with what we calculated on its left and above it.
           for (unsigned int c = 1; c < columns && c < splitPosition; ++c) {
               xorRow2.push_back({ });
               for (auto v : xorRow2[c - 1])
                   xorRow2[c].push_back(v ^ inputMatrix[r][c]);
               for (auto v : xorRow[c])
                   xorRow2[c].push_back(v ^ inputMatrix[r][c]);
           }
           std::swap(xorRow, xorRow2);
           if (columns >= splitPosition - r)
               xorOperand.push_back(xorRow[splitPosition - r - 1]);
       }
   };

   // XOR values for both MITM operands, representing where both areas meet in the matrix
   // Both variables will be initialized in the fillXorOperand lambda
   // Both variables are initialized with the number of vectors they will need in the end, representing how many cells are on the border.
   std::vector<XorValueList> xorLeft, xorRight;
   //xorLeft.resize(std::min(rows, columns), {}); xorRight.resize(std::min(rows, columns), {});

   // We fill the left operand. The first item in the vector will be the upmost, rightmost border cell of the matrix
   fillXorOperand(xorLeft);

   // We rotate the matrix 180° so that the bottom right cell comes to the top left
   // This is allowed because XOR is commutative (the operand order can be inverted).
   inputMatrix.flip();
   // Track where the diagonal moved during the flip
   splitPosition = rows + columns - splitPosition;

   for (unsigned int r = (splitPosition < columns ? 0 : splitPosition - columns); r < rows && r < splitPosition; ++r)
       inputMatrix[r][splitPosition - r - 1] = 0;

   // We fill the left operand. The first item in the vector will be the upmost, rightmost border cell of the flipped matrix, i.e. the downmost, leftmost border cell of the original matrix
   // We need to remember that when we do the correspondance between cells.
   fillXorOperand(xorRight);

   // The left operand is combined with the expected result, then all the vectors are sorted.
   for (auto& l : xorLeft) {
       for (auto& v : l)
           v = v ^ expected;
       std::sort(l.begin(), l.end());
   }
   // All the vectors in the right operand are sorted
   for (auto& r : xorRight) {
       std::sort(r.begin(), r.end());
   }

   auto lIter = xorLeft.cbegin();
   auto rIter = xorRight.crbegin();

   size_t result = 0;
   // We now need to "merge count" the cells shared on both operands, for the corresponding cells.
   // Here, merge count means count the identical cells in a loop similar to a merge-sort merging.
   for (; lIter != xorLeft.cend() && rIter != xorRight.crend(); ++lIter, ++rIter) {
       auto l = lIter->cbegin(), r = rIter->cbegin();
       while (l != lIter->cend() && r != rIter->cend()) {
           if (*l < *r)
               ++l;
           else if (*r < *l)
               ++r;
           else {
               //If *l == *r, we need to count all consecutive equal values.
               uint64_t value = *l;
               size_t a = 0, b = 0;
               for (; *l == value && l != lIter->cend(); ++l)
                   a += 1;
               for (; *r == value && r != rIter->cend(); ++r)
                   b += 1;
               result += a * b;
           }
       }
   }
   std::cout << result;

   auto end = steady_clock::now();
   auto ms_int = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
   std::cerr << "\nTime spent: " << ms_int.count() << ' ' << " ms\n" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some lightly tested and unoptimized Python. But heavily commented to help you make sense of it.

Good luck translating to C++.

```
def count_xor_paths (matrix, k):
    n = len(matrix)
    m = len(matrix[0])
    mid = (n + m)//2

    # We will be using dynamic programming to count paths that go
    # through a midpoint and xor to various values.
    #
    # The first and second halves go through 2 blocks that we will index
    # very differently. That's best described by a picture. Here is an
    # example for a 6x7 matrix. Where . is in a block, D is the diagonal,
    # and # is a point we are currently ignoring.
    #
    #          j1
    #        0 1 2 3
    #    0 [ . . . . # D #]
    # i1 1 [ . . . . D # #]
    #    2 [ . . . . . . .] 3 
    #      [ # # D . . . .] 2  j2
    #      [ # D # . . . .] 1 
    #      [ D # # . . . .] 0 
    #              3 2 1 0
    #                  i2
    #
    # The Python function range(n) generates numbers from 0, 1, ..., n-1.
    #
    # So here i1 is in range(3), j1 is in range(4), i2 is in range(4) and
    # j2 is in range(4). You can verify the following by inspection.
    #
    # In the first block, (i1, j1) is at matrix[i1][j1].
    # In the second block, (i2, j2) is at matrix[n-j2-1][m-i2-1].
    #
    # We index like this to create symmetry in how we handle the blocks.
    # But remembering the indexing is a PITA so let's hide it behind
    # utility functions.
    def value1 (i1, j1):
        return matrix[i1][j1]

    def value2 (i2, j2):
        return matrix[n-j2-1][m-i2-1]

    # The blocks meet at (2, 3) in the first being (3, 3) in the
    # first block meets the point (3, 3) in the second block.
    #
    # So we want:
    #
    #   i1 in range(n1): here n1 = 3
    #   j1 in range(m1): here m1 = 4
    #   i2 in range(n2): here n2 = 4
    #   j2 in range(m2): here m2 = 4
    #
    # where we only get nonempty ranges if:
    #
    #   0 < n1, n2, m1, m2
    #
    # And studying the indexes we get:
    #
    #   n1 + m2 = n + 1
    #   m1 + n2 = m + 1
    #
    # where n is the number of rows, and m the number of columns.
    #
    # Ideally with m1 + n1 close to n2 + m2. So 
    #
    #   (n1 + m1) = (n + m + 2)//2
    #
    # Let's start at the lowest left point where the diagonal hits the matrix.
    # Here either m1 or m2 will be 1. We fill in the rest from those rules.
    #
    if m <= n:
        # We hit on the left side of the matrix.
        # And so block1 is an n1x1 matrix.
        m1 = 1
        n2 = m 
        n1 = (n + m + 2)//2 - m1
        m2 = n + 1 - n1
    else:
        # We hit on the bottom of the matrix.
        # And so block2 is an n2x1 matrix.
        m2 = 1
        n1 = n 
        m1 = (n + m + 2)//2 - n1
        n2 = m + 1 - m1

    # Now our dynamic programming data structure will be:
    #
    # an array
    #    of arrays
    #      of dictionary lookups by xor of the path
    #          of the number of ways of getting that xor.
    #
    # Let's fill it in for block1 first.
    #
    # We have 1 way of getting the starting value.
    block1 = [ # array
                [ # of arrays
                    { # of dictionary lookups
                        value1(0, 0): # by xor of the path
                            1 # of the number of ways of getting that xor.
                            }]]
    # Fill in the rest of the first row.
    for j1 in range(1, m1):
        block1[0].append({})
        for k1, count in block1[0][j1-1].items():
            block1[0][j1][k1 ^ value1(0, j1)] = count

    # Fill in the other rows.
    for i1 in range(1, n1):
        # Start new row.
        block1.append([])
        for j1 in range(m1):
            # Create new dictionary for this spot in this row.
            cell = {}
            # Lookup the value in the matrix.
            v = value1(i1, j1)
            # Populate with move down.
            for k1, count in block1[i1-1][j1].items():
                cell[k1^v] = count
            # Add in move right.
            if 0 < j1:
                for k1, count in block1[i1][j1-1].items():
                    # The .get will get the value if it is
                    # there or 0 if it is not there.
                    cell[k1^v] = count + cell.get(k1^v, 0)
            # Add to block1[i1]
            block1[i1].append(cell)

    # Do exactly the same, except for block2
    block2 = [ # array
                [ # of arrays
                    { # of dictionary lookups
                        value2(0, 0): # by xor of the path
                            1 # of the number of ways of getting that xor.
                            }]]
    # Fill in the rest of the first row.
    for j2 in range(1, m2):
        block2[0].append({})
        for k2, count in block2[0][j2-1].items():
            block2[0][j2][k2 ^ value2(0, j2)] = count

    # Fill in the other rows.
    for i2 in range(1, n2):
        # Start new row.
        block2.append([])
        for j2 in range(m2):
            # Create new dictionary for this spot in this row.
            cell = {}
            # Lookup the value in the matrix.
            v = value2(i2, j2)
            # Populate with move left.
            for k2, count in block2[i2-1][j2].items():
                cell[k2^v] = count
            # Add in move up.
            if 0 < j2:
                for k2, count in block2[i2][j2-1].items():
                    # The .get will get the value if it is
                    # there or 0 if it is not there.
                    cell[k2^v] = count + cell.get(k2^v, 0)
            # Add to block2[i2]
            block2[i2].append(cell)

    # Now that we've filled it in, we can count paths through this point.
    answer = 0
    cell1 = block1[n1-1][m1-1]
    cell2 = block2[n2-1][m2-1]
    # We xor matrix[n1-1][m1-1] in both paths.
    # xor again to fix that.
    k1 = k ^ matrix[n1-1][m1-1]
    for v1, count1 in cell1.items():
        if v1^k1 in cell2:
            answer += count1 * cell2[v1^k1]

    # Now we just have to move up the diagonal.
    while 1 < min(n1, n2):
        # block1 loses its last row.
        n1 -= 1
        block1.pop()
        # block1 gains a new column.
        for i1 in range(n1):
            # Create a new cell
            cell1 = {}
            value = value1(i1, m1)
            # Populate it with move right.
            for k1, count1 in block1[i1][m1 - 1].items():
                cell1[k1 ^ value] = count1
            # Populate it with move down.
            if 0 < i1:
                for k1, count1 in block1[i1-1][m1].items():
                    if k1 ^ value in cell1:
                        cell1[k1 ^ value] += count1
                    else:
                        cell1[k1 ^ value] = count1
            # Add this cell to the block.
            block1[i1].append(cell1)
        # And now record that we have this column.
        m1 += 1

        # Do the same for block2.
        # block2 loses its last row.
        n2 -= 1
        block2.pop()
        # block2 gains a new column.
        for i2 in range(n2):
            # Create a new cell
            cell2 = {}
            value = value2(i2, m2)
            # Populate it with move up.
            for k2, count2 in block2[i2][m2 - 1].items():
                cell2[k2 ^ value] = count2
            # Populate it with move left.
            if 0 < i2:
                for k2, count2 in block2[i2-1][m2].items():
                    if k2 ^ value in cell2:
                        cell2[k2 ^ value] += count2
                    else:
                        cell2[k2 ^ value] = count2
            # Add this cell to the block.
            block2[i2].append(cell2)
        # And now record that we have this column.
        m2 += 1

        # Now that we've filled it in, we can count paths through this point.
        cell1 = block1[n1-1][m1-1]
        cell2 = block2[n2-1][m2-1]
        # Again correct for matrix[n1-1][m1-1] being xored on both blocks.
        k1 = k ^ matrix[n1-1][m1-1]
        for v1, count1 in cell1.items():
            if v1^k1 in cell2:
                answer += count1 * cell2[v1^k1]

    return answer
```